# How to show the additive property of a sum of a series

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

So I have been working on this proof for a bit now. I found a way to prove it directly, but am struggling to find a way to prove it with limits.

Question:

Let ∑an = A, ∑bn = B, for an, bn, A, B in the Reals,

show that ∑(an+bn) = (A+B)

Comment: what do you mean by limits?

Comment: You can first show that $\sum_{n=1}^{M}(a_n+b_n)=(\sum_{n=1}^{M}a_n)+(\sum_{n=1}^{M}b_n)$. This follows from the associativity and commutativity of the sum. Then we use that if $\lim_{M\to\infty}A_M$ and $\lim_{M\to\infty}B_M$ exist as finite limits, then $\lim_{M\to\infty}(A_M+B_M)$ exists and $\lim_{M\to\infty}(A_M+B_M)=\lim_{M\to\infty}A_M+\lim_{M\to\infty}B_M$. We use this property with $A_M=\sum_{n=1}^{M}a_n$ and $B_M=\sum_{n=1}^{M}b_n$.

Comment: ohhhhh okkk! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two convergent sequences, the limit of the sum is the sum of the limits. So you have
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n+b_n)&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^m(a_n+b_n)=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^ma_n+\sum_{n=1}^mb_n\right)\\ \ \\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^ma_n+\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^mb_n
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n+=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n
\end{align}